# php script for member approval by administrator

Tags: php

i created a register page n login page 4 members in php n mysql.and also i created a admin account and now i want to do something like if the member register he will be added only when the administrator approves it.please help

Answer (score 3):

The knee jerk reaction is to add a boolean column to the users table with a default value of false.  However the best route is probably a CHAR(1) column with a default of 'P' for pending.  Then when an admin makes a choice they can approve (set to 'Y') or deny (set to 'N') they won't have to look at everything (just list all users where the column is ='P')

Comment: Yes, that's pretty sound advice - a CHAR(1), or perhaps an ENUM containing valid account states.

Comment: @Rob - Ya good call, I agree ENUM is smarter, most important point here though is the three states instead of the kneejerk two

Answer (score 1):

1. Introduce an "approved" column into the user table which indicates whether or not the account is approved
2. Provide an interface for administrators to view a list of such accounts and toggle their approval status
3. Update existing authentication code to check this column and disallow the use of "unapproved" accounts

Comment: i am new to php so how can i provide interface for administrator to view a list of such accounts and toggle their approval status?

Comment: do u have any codes 4 that?if i read it i will be able to understand it

Comment: With regards to generating the list, I assume you can write a SELECT query and execute it? Toggling status is a simple UPDATE operation.